# Is there any way to get acces and change to Page before leave the server?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, global-asax, ads

I want to change page content while it is going from the server because i need to add some advertisements inside the html elements that are advertisement holder.

`protected void Application_PreSendRequestContent(object sender, EventArgs e)` this is good but i couldn't get access to `HttpContext` . Should i, i don't know :)

But in this method:
`protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` i could get the `HttpContext` but i couldn't find the server response in it.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a HttpModule instead of global.asax. You can find an example of a module that manipulates the response in MSDN: [Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx)

See also this page for some additional information (e.g. why a HttpModule instead of global.asax): [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)

---

To answer your comment: here are some reasons why to use a module instead of global.asax (have a look at the document linked above for more information):

- You can implement much of the functionality of a module in the application's Global.asax file [...] however, modules have an advantage over the Global.asax file because they are encapsulated and can be created one time and used in many different applications.
- In IIS 7.0, the integrated pipeline enables managed modules to subscribe to pipeline notifications for all requests, not just requests for ASP.NET resources.
- You can enable/disable a module via web.config (without touching any code)

You should use a module whenever you must create code that depends on application events, and when the following conditions are true:

- You want to re-use the module in other applications.
- You want to avoid putting complex code in the Global.asax file.
- The module applies to all requests in the pipeline (IIS 7.0 Integrated mode only).

Comment: Why do you offer HttpModudle instead of Global.asax? Can't i access to content of page?

Answer (score 0):

> protected void
>   Application_PreSendRequestContent(object
>   sender, EventArgs e) this is good but
>   i couldn't get access to HttpContext .
>   Should i, i don't know :)

You can always get access to the HttpContext for the current request by using `HttpContext.Current`